# Google Cloud and Android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, cloud

I am doing some RND for android and google cloud. Did some research on How i can utilize google cloud for android. I read some referrences and links where they explained about google storage and google sql where you need to pay or at least did the payment register to start up. Can anyone suggest me some references or link where i can read how i can utilize google cloud for android. For an example upload image using google app engine and get it via android. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a page about using [Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/)
You can use it with [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs), which is one of [cloud platforms](https://cloud.google.com/) that is offered Google:
[And here is the useful eclipse plugin for that](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae)